# laptop conecting as blutooth speaker

Tags: 17.10, bluetooth

i am using Ubuntu 17.10 .My problem is that when i am trying to connect my android phone via blutooth for transferring file. it will pair and connect  perfectly but my lap connect as a blutooth speaker.After connection when i play a music in my mobile the sound coming from my lap. just like a blutooth speaker.anybody know how to change this?

Comment: Transferring files over Bluetooth is not a good choice. Using ftp or sftp would give to you more transfer speeds in case both your phone and PC are in same WiFi networks. If Bluetooth is your requirement try Blueman Bluetooth manager to manage Bluetooth devices

Answer (score 0):

Audio playing over bluetooth is handled by the pulseaudio bluetooth module. For  a permanent fix uninstall the module:

```
sudo apt remove pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Reboot (or logout then login)

Unpair devices then pair again